# Custom WordPress Search Not Consistent with Results

Tags: php, wordpress

I've set up a custom search to use the s GET variable on a URL. I want it to fetch certain results but I've come across an odd problem. First, here's my code:

```
$search_term = $_GET['s'];

if($search_term!=''){
    $s = new WP_Query(array('s' => $search_term));
    $search_array = array();

    if($s->have_posts()){
        while($s->have_posts()){
            $s->the_post();

            $title = get_the_title();
            $permalink = get_permalink();
            $search_identifier = $title.$permalink;

            array_push($search_array,$search_identifier);
        }
    }
}
```

Essentially, I'm creating an array of unique values for each post because I need to use them for a function immediately after that.

I have a post titled 'Kitchen Assistant.' When I search 'kitchen', it shows up. When I search 'assistant' it does not show up.

I have other posts with the word 'assistant' in the title and content and those show up when I search 'assistant'. I'm curious as to why it would show up with one search term and not the other?

I've used var_dump($s) and the post is in the dump when I search 'assistant' but not when I search 'kitchen.'

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer to my own question (finally!). I'm using the NineToFive template and I guess by default there's a limit on the number of search results that's returned (I'm not sure if that's a WordPress default; maybe someone can clarify that).

I changed my query to this:

```
$s = new WP_Query(array('s' => $search_term, 'posts_per_page' => -1));
```

To not put a limit on the search results and that changed it. I needed to find every possible search term on page 1 in order to cross reference it with the location but it was 'paginating' the search results in search query end of it.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$search_term = $_GET['s'];
if(!empty($search_term)){

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'meta_query' => array(
            'key' => 'title',
            'value' => $search_term,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    );

    $s = new WP_Query($args);
    $search_array = array();

    if($s->have_posts()){
        while($s->have_posts()){
            $s->the_post();

            $title = get_the_title();
            $permalink = get_permalink();
            $search_identifier = $title.$permalink;

            array_push($search_array,$search_identifier);
        }
    }

}
```